# What is the name of the novel?

Tags: knowledge, real

Yesterday, after I picked up my son from fencing practice, we stopped at Krispy Kreme to get doughnuts, as per our tradition.  The total was $3.19. I paid with a five dollar bill and when I got my change, I noticed that the penny had the name of a novel on it.

**Which novel was it?**

*By the way, it is not an obscure novel.  Anybody familiar with Western Literature would know this novel.*

Comment: This seems a little vague. There appear to be a few valid answers.

Comment: @gnovice, added a clarification for future readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could've been

> 1984 (or 1919, 1942, 1968, 1945, ...): https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/18187.Books_With_a_Year_For_a_Title

Comment: I was wondering if this would be too easy or too hard. Guess I got my answer

Comment: Well done for getting the answer, but surely this is pretty broad as any coin could have any of those dates written... there seems to be a lot of extra unnecessary stuff in the question

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil there's a minimum number of characters required for the question.  I figured since this actually happened, I might as well tell how it happened and tag it with the "real" tag.

Comment: Don't they retire old pennies?

Comment: @PatrickT No.  Old paper bills, yes.

Comment: @Kevin, Indeed, I have looked it up: surprising to me (they do retire the damaged pennies and many were melted illegally at various times). But of course the percentage of pennies by mint year changes, which makes 1984 more likely than 1919, etc.. (I feel sorry for the current negative vote of your question, as I did upvote it, perhaps the wording could be made more precise)

Answer (score 4):

> ***Liberty*, by Garrison Keillor.**
>
>  The Jean Shepherd book *In God We Trust: All Others Pay Cash* has been suggested, but *: All Others Pay Cash* is absolutely part of the title, and it does not appear on the penny. I thus exclude that from consideration.
>
>  You didn't actually specify that you were paying with US currency, and Canada uses the dollar, the dollar sign, and has a coin commonly called a 'penny', but I didn't have one of those handy to check.
>
>  There are also several novels whose titles start with *E Pluribus Unum*, but as that is not the whole title for any of them, I exclude them as well, as with IGWT.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the name of the novel is

> [In god we Trust - All others pay cash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_God_We_Trust:_All_Others_Pay_Cash) by Jean Shepard in 1966

Because

The US Penny has the following written on the obverse side:

> [image]
>
> 'In god we trust'

And of course

> You paid with a bill, not in cash.

---

Alternatively

> The coin also has 'Liberty' written on it so could be that

Comment: Good guess, but that's not it.  "all others pay cash" is not on any penny I've ever seen.

Comment: @Kevin well there isn't much else written on the US Penny, except 'Liberty'. Unless the change you received is important...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - I can also find, instantly, "E Pluribus Unum", "One Cent", and "United States of America" on any penny I grab.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I should have said there isn't much else written on it that is the name of a novel

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1143808.E_Pluribus_Unum

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29241334-liberty

Comment: https://books.friesenpress.com/store/title/119734000022534162/Beaulena-C.-Dunn-In-God-We-Trust

Comment: @theonetruepath point taken... :P

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

> [In God We trust by Michael Harrington](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20648923-in-god-we-trust)

or

> [In God We trust by Winshluss, Frédéric Boniaud](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19164726-in-god-we-trust)

I found this question a little too broad, with many valid answers, so I don't know if this is correct.